# Cannot integrate Apache Commons VSF into JavaFX project

Tags: maven, javafx

I am having problems integrating the apache vfs2 commons library into my JavaFX project that is in vscode.  This is easy to duplicate if you create a template project and try to add this library to the template project.

Here is how to duplicate the problem in only a few minutes:

1. Bring up vscode and create a new JavaFX project by doing the following

   a. Ctrl-Shift P -> Java: Create Java Project...  -> JavaFx create from archetype (Provided by Maven for Java)

   b. Set group id to com.example

   c. Set artifact id to demofx

   d. Select Folder on resident computer

   e. When it asks for "Define value for property 'version' 1.0 SNAPSHOT: press enter

   f. Confirm by typing in 'Y' and pressing enter

   g. Open the project
2. Once the project is opened, add the library to the pom.xml file using the following dependency

   ```
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-vfs2 -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-vfs2</artifactId>
       <version>2.9.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   At this point, the project is rebuilt, and this library is added to the .m2 repository on my computer
3. When I try to use the library in a Java class (file), I add the following imports:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject;
   import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemOptions;
   ```

   Adding these imports gives the following errors:

   ```
   The type org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemOptions is not accessible Java(16778666)
   org.apache.commons
   ```
4. Add the following line to the module-info.java file:

   ```
   requires org.apache.commons;
   ```

   When I do this, it gives the following error:

   ```
   org.apache.commons cannot be resolved to a module Java(8389908)
   ```

I cannot go any further until these errors are resolved, and I don't know how to resolve them.

Here is the pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demofx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-vfs2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-vfs2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the module-info.java file:

```
module com.example {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires org.apache.commons;

    opens com.example to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like vfs2 is modular, in which case the automatic module will be determined by the jar file name (minus any version info in that file name). Check the name of the jar that was downloaded via Maven (I am guessing `commons-vfs2-x.y.z.jar`, in which case you would need `requires commons-vfs2`).

Comment: See [understanding modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).  Know that module names and package names are often different.  For more detailed info on modules, see tutorials such as from [Jenkov](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java/modules.html).

Comment: The name of the file that was downloaded by Maven was commons-net-3.9.0.jar.  If I add the following line to my module-info.java file from:
    requires org.apache.commons;
to:
    requires commons-net;
or:
    requires org.apache.commons-net;
This generates an error in the module-info.java file in that the '-' character is invalid

Comment: Good information jewelsea.  After reading the information in these links, it is still unclear to me how to use a non-modular jar file (commons-net-3.9.0.jar) in a modular application.  The mechanisms used to import the jar files (maven pom.xml) doesn't make them accessible to the other java files in the package.